# my mysql procedure already does insert, I would like to return the last inserted id

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, pdo

My procedures mysql already does inserts correctly:

this is my php code calling the procedure:

```
$sql = 'CALL insert_menu(?,?,?,?,?)';
        try {
                  $query = $bd->prepare($sql);
                  $query->bindParam(1,$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $query->bindParam(2,$catsup, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $query->bindParam(3,$level, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $query->bindParam(4,$link, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $query->bindParam(5,$title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                  $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

and this is my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_menu`(
IN p_cat_name VARCHAR(100),
IN p_cat_sup_cod INT,
IN p_cat_level INT,
IN p_link VARCHAR(200),
IN p_title VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
IF ((p_cat_name <> '')&&(p_cat_level <> '')&&(p_link <> '')&&(p_title <> '')) THEN
INSERT INTO access (access_id,menu_descr,sup_cod,level,menu_link,menu_title)
VALUES ('',p_cat_name,p_cat_sup_cod,p_cat_level,p_link,p_title);
END IF;
END;
```

I would like that my procedure returns to the php the last inserted id...
I also do not know how to get the result with PDO prepare...
I ask everyone's help, thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using PDO:

```
try {
    $bd->prepare('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
    $bd->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But this really doesn't need a prepare, so you could just use:

```
try {
    $results = $bd->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last');
    $lastID = $results[0]['last'];
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the LAST_INSERT_ID() need to be executed within the stored proc transaction to ensure you are getting the ID of the record inserted by the stored proc?

Comment: It is possible that a query be performed between the two. As you mentioned, you could either wrap the two in `beginTransation()` and `commit()` or executing them together.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```